# how to import telegram tdata into webogram

Tags: telegram

I'm using [webogram](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) to create a telegram based app and I have to work with tdata, and give it as an entry to my app do you have any suggestion about how to do this? what is the protocol?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by tdata: do you mean Telegram-data? How do you intend to use this as an entry point to your app? If you explain more, them we can help you figure out how to proceed.

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu for example when you go to the telegram directory you'll see a directory that names tdata. That's what I'm talking about and I have to work with such data. They give me tdata and I'll have to the authentication and extract other information from these data, and the registered phone number is also included in tdata. https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop that's the source code I'm using for my app.

Comment: In your question you mention webogram, here you mention tdesktop... Which is it?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu yeah sorry for that, webogram is the correct one.

Comment: so can you clearly spell out your use case?